# Cross Compilation of OpenSSL

Tags: windows, linux, macos, openssl, cross-platform

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build OpenSSL with MinGW in WIndows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379363/how-to-build-openssl-with-mingw-in-windows)

I have downloaded the OpenSSL source (openssl-1.0.1c) from their website. I need to build/compile this source, so that I can use the same on Windows, MAC and Linux environments. I google'd and read some blogs, but nothing sounds useful for me. If anybody has worked or anybody has relevant knowledge please help me!

**Compile once, use the same on all three different environments.**

Comment: You can find the answer in this post : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379363/how-to-build-openssl-with-mingw-in-windows

Comment: @physm Hey! I am asking cross compilation of OpenSSL, and you are redirecting me to on Windows(only) compilation.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at how the distro-specific packages are being built. Usually (in case of GPL, I think, mandatory) those scripts are shared. So you can work out the required details, and hook them up into your own desired build thingie.

Comment: @jalf Is it really not possible to develop something like a library (OpenSSL is based on C-language) that works on all three environments? And, C works on the environments (Windows, MAC & Linux). Please elaborate your point of view and idea.

Comment: @sehe Okay. I will. If any such, I will get back to you later.

Comment: @Charan: The C language works just fine under multiple operating systems. That is, the C *source code*. But when you compile it, you compile for a *specific* OS, using a *specific* executable format, and linking against *specific* OS APIs and libraries. And that won't work on another OS which exposes different APIs and libraries, and expects executables to use a different file format.

Comment: @jalf You are correct! I expected this. I did some ground work. As I learnt libraries on MAC are dylib files, on Windows dll files and on Linux .so files. But, I thought there has to be some way to compile that can be worked everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible, and it's not what cross compilation means. Cross-compiling means (for example), compiling for Windows while running in a Linux environment. It doesn't mean compiling something that will run under both Linux and Windows.

There is no way to build a single executable, which can be used on all three operating systems.

You have to compile the library once for Windows, once for Linux and once for Mac.