# How to ./configure -enable-openssl for libircclient?

Tags: openssl, mingw, msys

I'm trying to configure [libircclient](http://sourceforge.net/p/libircclient/) with OpenSSL but fails. Using MinGW msys:

```
X@X-PC /c/deps/libircclient
$ ./configure -enable-openssl
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
.......................etc etc
checking for CRYPTO_new_ex_data in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: OpenSSL not found
```

I have added those lines also but fails:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/c/deps/openssl-1.0.1l/include
LDFLAGS="-L/c/deps/openssl-1.0.1l
```

And it results in:

```
checking For MinGW32... no
checking for CRYPTO_new_ex_data in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... no
configure: error: OpenSSL not found
```

so `-lcrypto` is ok, but `-lssl`... no

What is the problem and the solution ?

---

OpenSSL built from source using:

```
cd /c/deps/
tar xvfz openssl-1.0.1l.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1l
./Configure no-zlib no-shared no-dso no-krb5 no-camellia no-capieng no-cast no-cms \
  no-dtls1 no-gost no-gmp no-heartbeats no-idea no-jpake no-md2 no-mdc2 no-rc5 \
  no-rdrand no-rfc3779 no-rsax no-sctp no-seed no-sha0 no-static_engine no-whirlpool \
  no-rc2 no-rc4 no-ssl2 no-ssl3 mingw64
make
```

Comment: `CPPFLAGS` is for the C preprocessor. Try `CFLAGS` and/or `CXXFLAGS` instead.

Comment: You did not use `--openssldir` with OpenSSL's `Configure`. Where, exactly, does OpenSSL install on MinGW? Or maybe, what did you do after entering `make`? Also see [How to build OpenSSL with MinGW in WIndows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9379363).

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled OpenSSL by itself?

If you have I would double check that OpenSSL has compiled properly, and make sure that the lib is in the root openssl directory (not, for example, /c/deps/openssl-1.0.1l/lib).

Comment: i've built openssl from source, i have no /lib dir on the openssl dir. i've added the openssl compiling lines on the OP please have a look

Comment: I would try removing all of those no-something options in the ./configure, it looks like you're disabling some SSL libraries, but I am not sure which actually creates the SSL library itself.

Comment: i have compiled lots of programs that require -lcrypto &  -lssl using this same openssl configurations without any problems. ill dig more and hope a new answer. PS : i have libcrypto.a and libssl.a in the openssl root

Comment: Now that is odd, one would assume that if it is finding one it would be able to find the other. The only thing I can think is that it checks for SSL_library_init and perhaps that is not in your particular version of libssl. Could you try running nm libssl.a in that directory and seeing if SSL_library_init is in the list of symbols?

Comment: yes, i got more than 2500 lines, and found SSL_library_init under ssl_algs.o:, ill compile an older openssl and test and share the results.