# Error while installing lua-requests using luarocks

Tags: lua, openssl, luarocks, luasec

Hello good people of stackoverflow,

I'm having trouble installing the lua-requests module using `luarocks install lua-requests` in the command line. A few of the dependencies of said module will be installed without a problem but `luasec` is causing a problem.

At first, I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\user>luarocks install luasec
Installing https://luarocks.org/luasec-0.9-1.src.rock

Error: Could not find header file for OPENSSL
  No file openssl/ssl.h in c:/external/include
  No file openssl/ssl.h in c:/mingw/include
  No file openssl/ssl.h in c:/windows/system32/include
You may have to install OPENSSL in your system and/or pass OPENSSL_DIR or OPENSSL_INCDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install luasec OPENSSL_DIR=/usr/local
```

However, I was able to fix it by downloading OpenSSL and using the following command in the command line:

`C:\Users\user>luarocks install luasec OPENSSL_DIR=" *path to openssl directory* "`

Which then led to the following error:

```
C:\Users\user>luarocks install luasec OPENSSL_DIR=" *path to openssl directory* "
Installing https://luarocks.org/luasec-0.9-1.src.rock

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibssl32MD
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibcrypto32MD
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Error: Build error: Failed compiling module ssl.dll
```

After googling for a while I found the following issue https://github.com/brunoos/luasec/issues/150.

I tried renaming the dll's but again no luck. So, now I'm kinda stuck and don't know what to do... I'd be extremely grateful if anyone had any tips or advice on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)

Comment: check this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9379363/how-to-build-openssl-with-mingw-in-windows)